# How to render the correct page/url with error messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, url-routing, render

**I have created an app that splits up a Student's Information into multiple forms.**

Everything works fine, but when I try to render Form_One after a Validation Error, it does not render the appropriate URL/Page.

```
EX.
   adults/1/students/2/form_one  

   turns into

   adults/1/students/2 

   I need to render the same url so I can proceed to form_2.
```

**MODELS**

```
class Adult < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students

end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :adult

  validates :firstName, :presence   => true,
                    length: { maximum: 50 }

  validates :lastName, :presence   => true,
                    length: { maximum: 50 }

end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
def update
  @adult = Adult.find(params[:adult_id])
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  if @student.update_attributes(student_params)

    ###IF PASS REDIRECT TO THE NEXT FORM
    if URI(request.referer).path == form_one_adult_student_path(@adult, @student)
      redirect_to form_two_adult_student_path(@adult, @student)
    elsif URI(request.referer).path == form_two_adult_student_path(@adult, @student)
      redirect_to form_three_adult_student_path(@adult, @student)
    else
      redirect_to adult_path(@district, @adult)
    end  
  else
    error_messages = @student.errors.messages
    @adult = Adult.find(params[:adult_id])
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.errors.messages.merge!(error_messages)

    ###IF ERROR AND ON FORM_ONE RENDER FORM_ONE
    if URI(request.referer).path == form_one_adult_student_path(@adult, @student)

      ###FOR SOME REASON THIS RENDERS adults/1/students/2
      ###BUT I NEED IT TO RENDER adults/1/students/2/form_one
      render 'form_one'
    end
  end
end

def form_one
  @title = "Student Information"
  @adult = Adult.find(params[:adult_id])
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end

def form_two
  @title = "Parent Information"
  @adult = Adult.find(params[:adult_id])
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
resources :adults do
  resources :students do
    member do
      get :form_one, :form_two
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ###FOR SOME REASON THIS RENDERS adults/1/students/2
  ###BUT I NEED IT TO RENDER adults/1/students/2/form_one
  render 'form_one'
```

Try `redirect_to` instead of `render`.

Keep in mind the difference between *rendering a template*, and making an *HTTP request*.  Try pretending you are an HTTP client and think about the requests and responses.  Sometimes it helps to look through your server log to see which controller actions happen, in which order.  Look for lines like `Processing students#update` or `Redirecting to ...`.

In the future, you may want to try [resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) like `#show` instead.